# Google Map not showing properly

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my case, I had used Google Map V1 API key for a long while(from windows machine). Due to my system crash i changed to Ubuntu.After that i could not able to view my map(it shows like grid view). when i surf from internet they said the problem with your API key.

For this i tried to regenerate new API but it was not avail for API v1 due to Google MAP version changes.

Also somebody suggested to upload APK in playstore and then download into a device.But i think it will not work...

Note :

I need a solution for how to use my old API Key in ubuntu OS then to look back mapview..
Because my projects were i am using in map v1 flows.kindly give solution for this...........

This is my error in logcat when accessing google map
Error:

```
(10:22) Palpandi: 06-04 14:38:12.628: W/System.err(652): IOException processing: 26
06-04 14:38:12.628: W/System.err(652): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
06-04 14:38:12.638: W/System.err(652):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted your operation system (Windows) and remove the `debug.keystore`  or `release.keystore` folder that was in your user folder without backing it up then there is nothing you can do to run you Google Maps API V1 application and display it's map.

Google Maps API V1 is deprecated for a while now and Google doesn't give keys for this API anymore. Your only choice to to move your application to use Google Maps API V2.

Here is a blog post I wrote on this topic that will get you started:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have your old debug.keystore (or release key used to sign app for Google Play), you can just forget about maps api v1.